# Display multiple comments in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Using AngularJS and try to posting multiple comments one after another. i am able to post one comment but when tried again it will replace with the existing and post the new.

**Attached snippet as well, what I tried**

I want like following:

```
1st comment submit : Hello !
2nd comment submit : Hi !
```

Result should be :

```
Hello !
Hi !
```

Here is my code

```js
var myApp = angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ui.bootstrap']);
 

function myCtrl($scope){
$scope.MakeVisible=!$scope.MakeVisible; 
$scope.showAddNoteBtn=true; 
$scope.userText='';
$scope.Test='';
$scope.MakeVisible=false;

  $scope.addNoteBtnClicked=function(){
 $scope.Test='';
 $scope.MakeVisible=true;
 $scope.showAddNoteBtn=false;
}
  
  $scope.cancel=function(){
 $scope.MakeVisible=false;
 $scope.showAddNoteBtn=true;
}

  $scope.Submit=function(){ 
 $scope.userText=$scope.Test;
 $scope.MakeVisible=false;
 $scope.showAddNoteBtn=true;
}



}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.0.js"></script>

<div ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <h5 style="color:#287ABE;margin-bottom:10px;">{{userText}}</h5>
  <h5 id="label" style="color:red;margin-bottom:10px;"></h5>
  <div ng-hide="MakeVisible">
  </div>
  <div ng-show="MakeVisible">
 <textarea ng-model="Test"></textarea>
     <input  type="button" value="Submit" ng-click="Submit()"/>
     <input  type="button" value="Cancel" ng-click="cancel()"/>
  </div>        
       
<div>
<input ng-show='showAddNoteBtn' type="button" value="Add Note" ng-click="addNoteBtnClicked()"/>
</div>         
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add the comments in to a array and iterate through the array

```js
var myApp = angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ui.bootstrap']);
 

function myCtrl($scope){
    $scope.MakeVisible=!$scope.MakeVisible; 
$scope.showAddNoteBtn=true; 
$scope.userText='';
$scope.Test='';
$scope.MakeVisible=false;
    $scope.addNoteBtnClicked=function(){
 $scope.Test='';
 $scope.MakeVisible=true;
 $scope.showAddNoteBtn=false;
}
    $scope.cancel=function(){
 $scope.MakeVisible=false;
 $scope.showAddNoteBtn=true;
}

   $scope.commentArray = [];    // array for storing comments

    $scope.Submit=function(){
 $scope.commentArray.push($scope.Test);     // add a comment to the array after user submit the comment
 $scope.MakeVisible=false;
 $scope.showAddNoteBtn=true;
}



}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.0.js"></script>

<div ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <h5 style="color:#287ABE;margin-bottom:10px;" ng-repeat="comment in commentArray">   
      {{ comment }}       
  </h5>
  <h5 id="label" style="color:red;margin-bottom:10px;"></h5>
  <div ng-hide="MakeVisible">
  </div>
  <div ng-show="MakeVisible">
 <textarea ng-model="Test"></textarea>
     <input  type="button" value="Submit" ng-click="Submit()"/>
     <input  type="button" value="Cancel" ng-click="cancel()"/>
  </div>        
       
   <div>
  <input ng-show='showAddNoteBtn' type="button" value="Add Note" ng-click="addNoteBtnClicked()"/>
  </div>         
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You use [arrays](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_array.asp) and [ngRepeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) directive to achieve it, like in this code snippet below:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ui.bootstrap']);
 

function myCtrl($scope){
$scope.MakeVisible=!$scope.MakeVisible; 
$scope.showAddNoteBtn=true; 
$scope.userText=[];
$scope.Test='';
$scope.MakeVisible=false;

  $scope.addNoteBtnClicked=function(){
 $scope.Test='';
 $scope.MakeVisible=true;
 $scope.showAddNoteBtn=false;
}
  
  $scope.cancel=function(){
 $scope.MakeVisible=false;
 $scope.showAddNoteBtn=true;
}

  $scope.Submit=function(){ 
 $scope.userText.push($scope.Test);
 $scope.MakeVisible=false;
 $scope.showAddNoteBtn=true;
}



}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.0.js"></script>

<div ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <h5 style="color:#287ABE;margin-bottom:10px;" ng-repeat="t in userText">{{t}}</h5>
  <h5 id="label" style="color:red;margin-bottom:10px;"></h5>
  <div ng-hide="MakeVisible">
  </div>
  <div ng-show="MakeVisible">
 <textarea ng-model="Test"></textarea>
     <input  type="button" value="Submit" ng-click="Submit()"/>
     <input  type="button" value="Cancel" ng-click="cancel()"/>
  </div>        
       
<div>
<input ng-show='showAddNoteBtn' type="button" value="Add Note" ng-click="addNoteBtnClicked()"/>
</div>         
</div>
```